zap_labels() clears tibble
I have a dataset imported to R from SPSS using the function read_sav(). I have tried to remove all labels using the zap_labels function as so:
    df <- read_sav("File 2023-2004.sav")

    dfsmall <- df %>% 
      dplyr::select(KM9, KM9_diko, FR4, FR4_diko, FR1_ny23_1, FR1_diko, KM7, 
      KM8)

    dfsmall_nl <- zap_labels(dfsmall)

There are no error message, and the labels are removed, but so is all the data. What did I do wrong and how can I remove the labels without deleting all the data
I tried one example from the function description, and turned it to a tibble just to ensure that was not the issue. Everything worked fine:
    x2 <- labelled_spss(c(1:4, 9), c(good = 1, bad = 5), na_values = 9)
    x2 <- tibble(x2)
    zap_labels(x2)

When I run the variables from my dataset through class() it gives this result:
    "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"
Here is the output from dput(head(dfsmall)). I removed a few questions to reduce the amount of output (and double checked that the problem is still there). The questions and answers are in Swedish, hopefully that won't be an issue.
   structure(
    list(
    KM9 = structure(c(5, 3, NA, 2, NA, 6), 
    label = "Hur mycket sitter du under ett normalt dygn?", 
    format.spss = "F1.0", labels = c(`Mindre än 4 timmar` = 1, 
    `4-6 timmar` = 2, `7-9 timmar` = 3, `10-12 timmar` = 4, `13-15 timmar` = 
    5, `Så gott som hela dagen` = 6), 
    class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 

    KM9_diko = structure(c(1, 0, NA, 0, NA, 1), 
    label = "Sitter 10 timmar eller mer per dygn", 
    format.spss = "F8.0", 
    display_width = 10L, 
    labels = c(Nej = 0, Ja = 1), 
    class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")),

    FR4 = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 0, NA, 0), 
    label = "Är du med i någon idrottsförening?", 
    format.spss = "F1.0", 
    labels = c(Nej = 0, `Ja, en` = 1, `Ja, flera` = 2), 
    class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 

    FR4_diko = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0), 
    label = "Är med i minst en idrottsförening", 
    format.spss = "F8.0", 
    display_width = 10L, labels = c(Nej = 0, Ja = 1), 
    class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), 

    class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
    groups = structure(
    list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
    ptype = integer(0), 
    class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")))


When I run zap_labels() on this it returns a data frame of numeric values. Is this not what you expect or are you finding different results on your full data frame?

That is what I want! Mine just goes completely blank - NA in all 4*6848 cells.

What about when you run it on the sample data frame you provided?

That one works fine, it removes the labels and keeps the numeric values.

"That one works fine, it removes the labels and keeps the numeric values.": so are you saying that your example is not reproducible?  That's not terribly helpful...

Ok now it works. It was a stupid thing - I did not realise I had two functions with the same name: haven::zap_labels() and sjlabelled::zap_labels(). When I specified haven everything worked just fine. I don't know why my example work and not the main file, but this is ok for now. Thank you for your time, and learning me how to do a reproducible example in a case like this.

@Limey I added that smaller example from the description of the package to show that I tried to search for errors that way - but did not find any. I thought it might be a clue to finding the issue that the function worked - but not on my actual data. I will keep in mind that it was a confusing rather than helpful for any future questions.

I'll answer my own question, if anyone else ever encounters this issue.
The problem was not specifying the package - I had sjlabelled and haven installed. The sjlabelled version of zap_labels()...

will replace all values that have a value label attribute with NA

So it did what it was supposed to do. Writing haven::zap_labels() solved this issue.

You may find the conflicted package useful and informative.
